QGIS: Further subdivide sub-catchments based on DEM
I have a DEM and a vector layer with existing hydrological sub-catchments. Is there a way in QGIS to further subdivide the sub-catchments based on the DEM?


The correct way to do this is to recreate the catchments with a smaller threshold value.

I have done that. However, I got the sub-catchment areas shown from my supervisor and they were created with a different DEM. Now I have smaller sub-catchments that were created independently of the existing sub-catchments. I just thought there might be a way to further divide the existing sub-catchments within their boundaries.

Can you use the "different DEM"?
